# Absense of cases in Bulgarian

Tags: grammar, language-change, cases, slavic-languages

Nowadays, Bulgarian and Macedonian are the only Slavic languages where the system of cases isn't developed. Bulgarian and Macedonian are very close to each other, but are considered to be 2 independent languages though previously Macedonian was supposed to be a dialect of the Bulgarian language.
 The countries where these languages are spoken have boundaries with other Slavic countries.So they've always been in close cultural connections and had influence on each other's language.However, the closest Bulgarian Slavic neighbour, Serbia, has still kept 7 cases system.So my question is: how can it be explained that Bulgarian lost its cases?

Comment: Bulgaria and North Macedonia _don't_ "have boundaries with other Slavic countries", they border only on Serbia. And Bulgarian still has cases, Nominative, Accusative, Dative in pronouns, and Nominative and Oblique in definite nouns. Also, nouns have Vocative case. Anyhow, Bulgarian is geographically on the periphery of the Slavic world, so no surprise it developed some features other Slavic languages don't have.

Comment: @YellowSky "on the periphery" is questionable, it's not any more peripheral than Polish, or Russian in Siberia.  Also Old Church Slavonic - which has cases - was developed there and was in diglossia.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer - Old Church Slavonic is irrelevant in this discussion since it appeared 1000+ years ago when all the Slavic languages were just dialects.

Comment: @YellowSky Why would it's age make it *less* relevant?  It's basically a snapshot of Macedo-Bulgarian a thousand years ago.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer - 1000 years ago all the Slavic languages were just dialects, the differences were only on the phonetic level, not in grammar. Now we are talking about 2 languages which are grammatically rather different from the rest. Can you see now why it's useless to talk about OCS here? Do you acquire my drift?

Comment: The question is precisely why it is different than the rest, including different from OCS, with which it was in constant contact.  Comparative method won't work well if we just ignore a comparable language.  The fact that that language has a solid written record is only a plus.

Comment: (I also dispute the bizarre claim that Slavic languages/dialects from Prussia to Thesaloniki to Muscovy had no grammatical differences 1000 years ago.  It's non-falsifiable at best, but that's just not how language works.)

Comment: @YellowSky I do not think that's a verifiable statement about grammar (as Adam says). It might have gone either way, all Slavic sprang from OCS, or it's an adstratum to already similar languages. It might be indeed as you say, that OCS is not very relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

The features of Bulgarian and Makedonian are explained by mutual influence of the languages on the Balkan (including non-Slavonic Languages such as Romanian, Albanian, and Greek). The neighbouring languages of Bulgarian show a characterisitc reduction of the case system to 2 cases (3 including vocative) with genitive and dative merged into one case. Due to their mutual influence the Balkan languages form a *sprachbund* named [Balkan sprachbund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balkan_sprachbund).

Comment: Romanian, Albanian and Greek have case.  Lack of case is *not* a feature of the Balkan sprachbund.

Comment: And Romanian (or more precisely Eastern ie Balkan Romance) is the only modern vulgar Romance branch that has case.

Comment: But reduction of case to a 2 (or 3 with vocative) case system with same endings for genitive and dative is.

Comment: Your answer would be improved by including that, and why it applies here, because it's not obvious Macedo-Bulgarian even has genitive/dative, or any cases at all beyond pronouns.

Comment: Given that Macedo-Bulgarian has *less* case morphology than the rest, it's not obvious it's an effect of this tendency in the sprachbund, rather than the cause.

Comment: This lacks reason. What kind of influence? If you can exclude other possibilities, you must go into detail, if you can exclude other possibilities. English would be another example of sever morpheme loss, and it's imho, indecisive between reductive soundshift and foreign language influence. However, in that light, influence of a heavily latinized language would be a strong point, if there's evidence. More so, if the feedback loop reacted onto Romanian in turn. But Greek would be a stretch, I say. What about Persian, Turkic, arabic, etc; cp English creole hypothesis?